# Vaadin + Spring boot application very slow after long idle time

Tags: java, performance, spring-boot, vaadin

I have a performance problem with my Vaadin 8 + Spring Boot application.

When I start the application after a long time without using, for example after one night, it tooks several minutes to get the response from the database.

I have following application settings:

```
    spring.datasource.max-active=10
    spring.datasource.initial-size=5
    spring.datasource.max-idle=5
    spring.datasource.min-idle=1
    spring.datasource.test-while-idle=true
    spring.datasource.test-on-borrow=true
    spring.datasource.validation-query=SELECT 1
    spring.datasource.time-between-eviction-runs-millis=5000
    spring.datasource.min-evictable-idle-time-millis=60000
```

Without `test-while-idle`, `validation-query` and `test-on-borrow` I couldnt even reconnect to the database again but the performance problem is still present.

Comment: First of all, you should isolate the problem. Add timing logs to your application around database calls if you suspect them to be slow. Another possible reason for slow Java applications can be a memory leak which will invoke garbage collection more often and end with a OutOfMemoryException finally. In that case you could print GC logs or take a heap dump when your application is slow.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a JDBC connection which has been idle so long it has been timed out on the TCP/IP level. I wonder if there is either a setting that would auto-close JDBC connection after it has not been used for, say, 2 minutes. Or a heart-beat setting that would issue `SELECT 1` every 5 minutes on all JDBC connections, to keep it alive.